# Delete row with joinTable Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

first sorry for my english, it's not my native language.

So, i want to delete a row from a table :

```
@ORM\Table(name="demandes")
class Demande
{
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Site", cascade="all", orphanRemoval=true)
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="demandes_sites",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="demande_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="site_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")}
 *      )
 * @Assert\Count(min = 1)
 */
private $sites;
}
```

But when i delete, i have this error :

```
An exception occurred while executing 'DELETE FROM demandes WHERE numero_qc = ?' with params ["test delete"]:

SQLSTATE[23503]: Foreign key violation: 7 ERROR: update or delete on table "demandes" violates foreign key constraint "fk_7c6153f880e95e18" on table "demandes_sites"
DETAIL: Key (id)=(52) is still referenced from table "demandes_sites".
```

What am i doing wrong ?

**Edit :**
After doing `php console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql --force`

I have this exit :

`ALTER TABLE demandes_sites DROP CONSTRAINT FK_7C6153F880E95E18;
ALTER TABLE demandes_sites DROP CONSTRAINT FK_7C6153F8F6BD1646;
ALTER TABLE demandes_sites ADD CONSTRAINT FK_7C6153F880E95E18 FOREIGN KEY (demande_id) REFERENCES demandes (id) ON DELETE CASCADE NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE;
ALTER TABLE demandes_sites ADD CONSTRAINT FK_7C6153F8F6BD1646 FOREIGN KEY (site_id) REFERENCES sites (id) ON DELETE CASCADE NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE;`

The right solution for me was tu update database schema. My mistake is that i didnt see the error that blocked the maj and was thinking it was made correctly

Thanks to all who helped me

Comment: Try to delete cache and update schema..

Comment: You need to delete records from "demandes_sites" table related to record you are trying to delete from table "demandes"

Comment: Delete cache didn t work
 / 
The attribute onDelete="CASCADE" isn't suposed to delete related records of "demandes_sites" for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you added the
`onDelete="CASCADE"`
options when you had already generated the model on the DB and you didn't update.

Verify what happens with the command

```
 php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
```

Comment: i have : [InvalidArgumentException] The directory "XXX" is not writable. I also do it with --force option, same result. I think it says that i havent written right

Comment: Try deleting all files in `app/cache` and `app/logs` and then setting proper permissions  `chmod 777 app/cache app/logs` and repeat previous commands

Comment: As i was thinking it was written acces matter. I sudo the command and it passed. I edit the question to put the output.

Comment: Your output confirms what I said in my answer, so you fixed it with `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`

Comment: Yes but as i explained up, i have some exception that blocked the update so i run manually the sql to the table.